# android, Can I forward phone number data to google duo?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-duo

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.tachyon");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "phonenumber"));
startActivity(intent);
```

I could not pass the data to 'Google duo' app in the same way

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    Intent duo = new Intent("com.google.android.apps.tachyon.action.CALL");
    duo.setData(Uri.parse("tel: " + phoneNumber));
    duo.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.tachyon");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(duo, "Duo is not installed."));
```

Comment: While this may solve the problem, to make this useful to other readers, include some explaination as to why this would solve the problem.